# Cascade SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below database structure for a module I'm developing,

There are many institutions, each one wants to see the tasks assigned to the subdivision below it

Each institution is composed of users.

Institution, T1, T2, T3, T4 are institutions

```
Institution sees itself, T1, T2, T3, T4
T1 Sees itself, T2, T3, T4
T3 Sees itself, T4
T4 Sees itself
T2 Sees itself

---------------   ----------   ---------   ---------   ---------
| Institution |   |    T1  |   |  T2   |   |  T3   |   |  T4   |
---------------   ----------   ---------   ---------   ---------
| id          |   | id     |   | id    |   | id    |   | id    |
| prior       |   | instId |   | t1Id  |   | t1Id  |   | t3Id  |
|             |   | prior  |   | prior |   | prior |   | prior |
---------------   ----------   ---------   ---------   ---------

-----------------   
| User          |  
----------------- 
| id            | 
| institutionId | 
-----------------
```

`prior is priority (I thought of adding this field to help the cascading select)`

Now, the system I'm working on was allowing users to see all the tasks of all the institution whatever their level were (+1000 tasks / day). 
The system has 1 input data, the userId retrieved when a user loggs-in to see his tasks, I should only allow him to see his institution or sub-institutions.
I managed to show only his institution tasks but I need now to allow him see everything on cascad.

p.s : I'm using SQL Server on Dev, but Oracle on Prod.. So, it would be nice to have something generic :)

How do I do this?

Comment: Why are you using SQL Server on Dev but Oracle on Prod.?

Comment: @Shaneis : because on Dev I'm using a VM with SQL Server on it and I don't have visibility on the Prod env of the customer. Their teams are responsible for porting my code there.